# File Transfer in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, file-transfer

I am trying to implement File transfering with sockets in java. I came so far but the problem that I cannot send the file to the server. Client does not write contents of the file. I know that I need to create a loop, but I couldn't do that. Can you please check the code? I cannot see the problem.

**Client Side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
// Class Client Socket
public class ClientSocket
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // show main Menu
        System.out.println("Basic Client Socket Programming");
        // Socket Variables
        Socket clientSocket = null;             // for sending and receiving of data
        PrintWriter  outputStream = null;       // for sending data
        BufferedReader  inputStream = null;     // for receiving data
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        BufferedOutputStream bos;
        // Create and open socket
        // Connection to 127.0.0.1, port num=2001
        try
        {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",  2001);
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: 127.0.0.1");
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: 127.0.0.1");
            return;
        }
        // check if connection is successful
        if((clientSocket == null) || (outputStream == null) || (inputStream == null))
        {
            System.err.println("Socket Connection not successfull");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Socket Connected");
        }
        //generate MD5 and send data
        String hash = MD5.md5("Hello");
        System.out.println("Hash code generated: "+hash);
        //outputStream.println("Hello ||" + hash);
        //creates a new BufferWriter to write the hash value and the text message into the txt file.
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("hashedCode.txt"));
        out.write(hash); //writes the hash code to the file
        out.close(); //close the bufferreader
        //Send the file to the server
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("hashedCode.txt"));
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
        int in;
        while ((in = bis.read(byteArray)) != -1)
        {
            bos.write(byteArray,0,in);
        }
        // receiving data
        String rcvData;
        rcvData = inputStream.readLine();
        System.out.println(rcvData);
        // close connections
        try
        {
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            bis.close();
            bos.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
        }
        // exit program
        return;
    }
}
```

**Server Side**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class serverSocket
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        // show main Menu
        System.out.println("Basic Client Socket Programming");
        // Socket Variables
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;       // for listen for connection
        Socket  rcvSocket = null;               // for sending n rcving data
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;   // for sending data
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;     // for receiving data
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        BufferedOutputStream bos;
        int inInt;
        byte[] data;
        // try to open a socket to listen for incoming data
        // port number must match the one that the client is connecting to
        try
        {
           serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2001);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
           System.err.println(e);
        }
        // creating a socket to rcv incoming data
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Listening");
                rcvSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(rcvSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rcvSocket.getInputStream()));
                /*
                // initiate conversation with client
                String rcvData = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Rcv Data: " + rcvData);
                */
            byte[] receivedData = new byte[8192];
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(rcvSocket.getInputStream());
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("receivedHashed.txt"));
            while ((inInt = bis.read(receivedData)) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(receivedData,0,inInt);
            }
            bos.flush();
                out.println("File received!");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
               System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have already created a loop. There is no UDP here, only TCP. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to flush the bytes you've written out of the buffered output stream?

```
while ((in = bis.read(byteArray)) != -1)
{
    bos.write(byteArray,0,in);
}
bos.flush();
```

Comment: Or indeed *close* it.

Comment: `bos.close()` is already called in the next `try` block where all the other resources are also closed.  But, if close() implicitly calls flush(), that call to close() is "too late" in this code snippet because it is also after the input stream is checked for response data.